# Wood floor protection during demolition of roof

Tags: remodeling

I need ideas how to  best protect wood floors while roof is coming down during remodel. Roof is made of heavy materials (concrete,brick, metal, etc.)

Comment: For a bathroom remodel we used Ram Board rolls on all of our hardwood floors and it worked great. It might not prevent dents from dropping a brick.

Answer (score 9):

It would be very worth investing in at least two layers of protection. I'd start with something that will accommodate dust and debris. It should seal against them, but it should also cushion them if they do work their way in. There are some felt-lined plastic products to be found, and there are some paper-based products that would do as well. Roll them out and tape the seams. Also tape the perimeter with something that won't leave stains or residue.

Next, buy a stack of inexpensive sheet material--1/4" OSB, luan plywood, or cdx plywood. Lay it out to cover as much of the area as possible. Overlap if necessary. Place the nicer face down to preserver it for re-use or re-sale after the project is complete.

It might then make sense to tarp over it all as a  debris-collection mechanism, so that you can pick up at the end of each day and shake it out elsewhere. Debris management is as much a part of the equation as the protection itself. You don't want plaster or masonry crumbs, loose nails, etc. on the floor longer than necessary.

Finally, give the area a good vacuum cleaning whenever you can work it in. Nothing beats suction to pull damaging debris out of tight places.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. A side note, the site prep should be the contractors job, unless it was understood otherwise.

Comment: I'd use 1/2" osb, instead of 1/4" ply

Comment: 1/2" is much heavier, obviously. It also creates a substantially larger trip hazard where it's lapped because it isn't as flexible. Unless you actually expect full bricks to be dropped from altitude, 1/4" is likely adequate.

Comment: I suggest looking for Gaffer Tape to secure the dust protection layer. It is fabric based so it won't tear when puling it up (unlike masking tape) and it doesn't leave adhesive residue (unlike duct tape).

Would Geo-cloth work as a dust layer? It might be less expensive and easier to find than felt lined products.